# Router hardware / software supports MLPPP with 4+ interfaces

Tags: networking, router, dsl

I am looking for a router that will support 4-5 MLPPP interfaces. I have been using the tomato mlppp patch from [fixppp.org](http://fixppp.org/) which works fine for 2 interfaces. As soon as I try and add a third interface it doesn't seem to work properly with the wrt54g. I have looked into ZeroShell and tried to install this but the hardware that I have (PC with Dlink dfe-530tx) has issues with the network cards for some reason.

So what I am looking for is some commercial or otherwise solution that is less than $800 and will support at least 4 MLPPP interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

MLPPP is supported in any Cisco router capable of running IOS 11.1.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) ([download](http://m0n0.ch/wall/downloads.php), [docs](http://m0n0.ch/wall/documentation.php)) will support what you're looking for.

Combined with some of the available [Soekris](http://www.soekris.com/) boards, or other devices as you prefer, it appears to be able to handle this situation.

Comment: I can't find anything stating that m0n0wall supports MLPPP. Also I can't find a Soekris board that has 4 ports.

Comment: I believe some of the add-in boards for the Soekris bases will - but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

The Mikrotik [Routerboard RB750](http://routerboard.com/index.php?showProduct=56) has 5 ports, supports MLPPP, and costs ~$40.  There have previously been [discussions on Broadband Reports](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r23179035-MLPPP-and-MikroTik) with reports of good success bonding 4 DSL lines together.  Mikrotik also sells various other hardware for additional larger loads.

Comment: Only client side - no MLPPP server included. SUCKS but that is how it is.

Comment: What the hell is with the down votes?  The guy was clearly looking to do client-side mlppp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the Microtik gear (personal preference).

Another option from a more well known vendor is the [Juniper SRX100](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/srx-series/srx100/). This also supports MLPPP, and is ~$500. The larger versions have direct ADSL & T1 interfaces (mutiple on the SRX240, albeit well above your budget).